# Function not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to make some controls to the box move to left, right, up and down. But when i make all the functions in the script tag, it get an error (in all the four `onclick` button):

> Function not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

in the lines that i make the button tag.

```html
<html>
<button onclick = "leftmove()" id = "b1"> Left </button>
<button onclick = "rightmove()" id = "b2"> Right </button>
<button onclick = "upmove()" id = "b3"> Up </button>
<button onclick = "downmove()" id = "b4"> Down </button>
<h1 id = "box"></h1>
<style type = "text/css">
#box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

<script>
var box = document.getElementById("box");
function leftmove() {
    margin += 2;
    box.style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
}
var box = document.getElementById("box");
function rightmove() {
    margin -= 2;
    box.style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
}
var box = document.getElementById("box");
function upmove() {
    margin += 2;
    box.style.marginTop = margin + "px";
}
var box = document.getElementById("box");
function downmove() {
    margin -= 2;
    box.style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Move the `<script>` block with the functions before the elements that will use these functions (which in your case will [require](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) you to use `<body>` tags)

Comment: no body tags arenot the issue, the variable margin has simply not been defined yet

Comment: By the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-body-element) @Andreas is right about it, but browsers might run it anyway.

Comment: @tacoshy You are only permitted to omit the `<body>` tags in specific cases (see the link). If OP moves the `<script>` above the `<button>`s it is no longer possible to omit `<body>`. And just because somethings "works" doesn't make it valid.

Comment: andreas I'm aware of that. Thats however not the issue here. the issue here is, that the script is working with variabels that have not been defined. The snippet of the code proided ehre, simply is cut down and not complete. But liek I said, the missing viriables preventing the script to work in the first place.

Comment: Duplicate declaration `var box = document.getElementById("box");` here in the code is a syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

When using `<script>` tags like this, the functions and targeted tags have to be defined before usage. To make you example work you have to split you script tag to first define you functions and set the `box` variable later, after you have defined the corresponding tag. Also the `margin` variable is missing, I added is as zero but that's probably not how you want it. Working example:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    var margin = 0;

    function leftmove() {
      margin += 2;
      box.style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
    }

    function rightmove() {
      margin -= 2;
      box.style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
    }

    function upmove() {
      margin += 2;
      box.style.marginTop = margin + "px";
    }
    var box = document.getElementById("box");

    function downmove() {
      margin -= 2;
      box.style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
    }
  </script>

  <button onclick="leftmove()" id="b1"> Left </button>
  <button onclick="rightmove()" id="b2"> Right </button>
  <button onclick="upmove()" id="b3"> Up </button>
  <button onclick="downmove()" id="b4"> Down </button>
  <h1 id="box"></h1>
  <style type="text/css">
    #box {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

A few notes aside the question:

- A `<div>` might be more appropriate instead of the `<h1>` for the box
- For rendering performance you would be better of using `transform(x, y)` instead of margins to move the box

Answer (score 0):

Some JavaScript variables were created to manipulate the CSS indirectly. Other elements were also implemented to better understand the movements.

```html
<html>
<style type = "text/css">
#box {
    margin: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}
</style>

<button onclick = "start()" id = "b0"> Start </button>
<button onclick = "leftmove()" id = "b1"> Left </button>
<button onclick = "rightmove()" id = "b2"> Right </button>
<button onclick = "upmove()" id = "b3"> Up </button>
<button onclick = "downmove()" id = "b4"> Down </button>
<div id="box"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var box = document.getElementById("box");
var margin = 10;
var marginX = 100;
var marginY = 100;

function start(){
    box.style.margin = "100px";
    marginX = 100;
    marginY = 100;
}

function leftmove() {
    marginX -= margin;
    box.style.marginLeft = marginX + "px";
}

function rightmove() {
    marginX += margin;
    box.style.marginLeft = marginX + "px";
}

function upmove() {
    marginY -= margin;
    box.style.marginTop = marginY + "px";
}

function downmove() {
    marginY += margin;
    box.style.marginTop = marginY + "px";
}

</script>
</html>
```